# Using proxies, but it's still forwarding my own ip adress

Tags: python, proxy, python-requests, ip

Unfortunately, this is the fifth time that I'm trying ask this. I created a program that checks against an api. To avoid ip-based rate limits I rotate proxies, however its still passing my own ip address.

Code:

```
    with open('external/proxies.txt', 'r') as proxyFile:
        proxyList = [proxyIp.strip() for line in proxyFile.readlines() for proxyIp in line.split(',') if proxyIp]

    def proxies(self):
        self.randomProxy = random.choice(self.proxyList)
        return {'http': f'http://{self.randomProxy}'}

    def login(self):
        while True:
            try:
                self.proxy = self.proxies()
                self.creds = self.accounts()
                self.headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + self.creds
                r = requests.post("https://public-ubiservices.ubi.com/v3/profiles/sessions", json={"Content-Type":"application/json"}, headers=self.headers, proxies=self.proxy)
                print(f"{Fore.LIGHTBLACK_EX}[+]{Fore.RESET} {r.status_code} - Attempting: {self.proxy} - Recieved: {r.json()['clientIp']}")

            except KeyError: 
                pass
```

Output of the code:

```
[+] 200 - Attempting: {'http': 'http://60.191.11.249'} - Recieved: my.own.ip.adr
[+] 200 - Attempting: {'http': 'http://47.254.75.151'} - Recieved: my.own.ip.adr
[+] 200 - Attempting: {'http': 'http://20.197.187.216'} - Recieved: my.own.ip.adr
```

Comment: `requests.post("https...` but the proxies are just set for `http`

Comment: @MauriceMeyer I changed it to also do https, however that just gives connection errors: `HTTPSConnectionPool(host='public-ubiservices.ubi.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /v3/profiles/sessions (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000018E199A28B0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond')))`